# psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "blah"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

On CentOS, I am trying to use rake to migrate data from sqlite3 to postgresql.

When I try to connect to PostgreSQL using the command line:

```
psql -d <db> -U <user> -W
```

I get:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "blah"
```

For testing I even set method to trust for psql. Here are the contents of my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Do you connect from the local machine, or from remote? 2) What are the -d -U -W flags suppsed to do ? 3) What is in the logfile ?

Comment: Also, did you reload / restart PostgreSQL after changing the authentication config file?

Answer (score 3):

Restart PostgreSQL and if that fails post the *full* pg_hba.conf for us to look at.

Either PostgreSQL has not reloaded this file or you are looking at the wrong pg_hba.conf.